# Error: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry fails on building

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The error i got is:
       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
     java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:       com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqr.class

I have been stuck for hours on this issue.

Here is my Build.Gradle (app file) .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
}



android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 140
    versionName "1.4.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
// Android SDK
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
// Audience Network SDK. Only versions 4.6.0 and above are available
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0+'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar') {
   transitive = true;
}
}

crashlytics {
enableNdk true
androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same class with different versions twice.
You are using the Google play services modules with different releases:

Use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```